# Duplicated lines easier to read vs DRY

Tags: powershell

Please see the file [here](https://github.com/VijayS1/windows-dev-box-setup-scripts/blob/master/scripts/MouseCursorSettings.ps1), reproduced below in separate sections.
My question is basically

1. Which way is better?
2. Which is easier to understand?
3. Which is easier to modify?
4. What should be the priority? Modification or Understanding?

NEW WAY, using variables & loops, trying to deduplicate as much as possible. Ideally should have one array to change only.

```
$regpath = "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors"
$cursorpath = "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Cursors\"

$suffix = "_eoa.cur"
$settings = @(@{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="String";       Name="(Default)";     Value="Windows Inverted"}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="DWord";        Name="CursorBaseSize";  Value=64}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="DWord";        Name="Scheme Source"; Value=2}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="Appstarting";     Value=$cursorpath + "busy"   +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="Arrow";           Value=$cursorpath + "arrow"  +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="Crosshair";       Value=$cursorpath + "cross"  +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="Hand";            Value=$cursorpath + "link"   +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="Help";            Value=$cursorpath + "helpsel"+$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="IBeam";           Value=$cursorpath + "ibeam"  +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="No";              Value=$cursorpath + "no"     +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="NWPen";           Value=$cursorpath + "pen"    +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="Person";          Value=$cursorpath + "person" +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="Pin";             Value=$cursorpath + "pin"    +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="SizeAll";         Value=$cursorpath + "move"   +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="SizeNESW";        Value=$cursorpath + "nesw"   +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="SizeNS";          Value=$cursorpath + "ns"     +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="SizeNWSE";        Value=$cursorpath + "nwse"   +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="SizeWE";          Value=$cursorpath + "ew"     +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="UpArrow";         Value=$cursorpath + "up"     +$suffix}
              @{Path="."; Force=$true; PropertyType="ExpandString"; Name="Wait";            Value=$cursorpath + "wait"   +$suffix}
             )

Set-Location $regpath #set location to registry folder where we will make all changes
#$DebugPreference = "Continue"
foreach ($regkey in $settings) {
    New-ItemProperty @regkey #create all the registry keys
    Write-Debug ($regkey | Out-String)
}
#$settings.ForEach(New-ItemProperty @_) #alternative method testing
```

OLD WAY. Using only 1 variable.

```
#Set Mouse Pointer Scheme to Windows Inverted, large size
$cursorpath = "%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Cursors\" #this references the environment variable directly
##$cursorpath = "%SystemRoot%\cursors\" #this references the environment variable directly
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name "(Default)"      -Value "Windows Inverted"                    -PropertyType String       -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name CursorBaseSize   -Value 64                                    -PropertyType DWord        -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name "Scheme Source"  -Value 2                                     -PropertyType DWord        -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name AppStarting      -Value ($cursorpath + "busy"   + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name Arrow            -Value ($cursorpath + "arrow"  + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force #same
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name Crosshair        -Value ($cursorpath + "cross"  + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name Hand             -Value ($cursorpath + "link"   + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name Help             -Value ($cursorpath + "helpsel"+ "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name IBeam            -Value ($cursorpath + "ibeam"  + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force #same
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name No               -Value ($cursorpath + "no"     + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force #same
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name NWPen            -Value ($cursorpath + "pen"    + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name Person           -Value ($cursorpath + "person" + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force #same
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name Pin              -Value ($cursorpath + "pin"    + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force #same
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name SizeAll          -Value ($cursorpath + "move"   + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name SizeNESW         -Value ($cursorpath + "nesw"   + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name SizeNS           -Value ($cursorpath + "ns"     + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name SizeNWSE         -Value ($cursorpath + "nwse"   + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name SizeWE           -Value ($cursorpath + "ew"     + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name UpArrow          -Value ($cursorpath + "up"     + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\Cursors" -Name Wait             -Value ($cursorpath + "wait"   + "_eoa.cur") -PropertyType ExpandString -Force #same
# It's so annoying that only 6/17 names are the same. I guess it'd due to changes in modern thinking about naming conventions and how they thought
#previously. This raises the question about how to do it right in OSes? That's why APIs are hard I guess.
```

Answer (score 2):

If path is always . and force is always true, why are you always setting them? It inhibits readability.

The priority should always be understanding, because well understood code can be made more modular by anyone (e.g. you in the future), but it's far harder to update code that you don't understand.

It's pretty easy to tell what you're doing already though. If you wanted to be minimalist, you functionally have key/value pairs of strings, and could just store them in an array or hashtable to send to New-ItemProperty.

I would personally lay it out like:

1. declare a lambda that adds non-cursor entries
2. declare a lambda that adds cursor entries
3. Pipe a table of Key:Value pairs into lambda from step 1
4. Pipe a table of cursor names to cursor paths into lambda from step 2

The reasoning is that:

- Pretty close to the minimal amount of code
- Configuration is at the top of the file: the registry paths, cursor paths, and the mapping of friendly cursor names to paths is in the first two lines
- Hashtables are hard to get typos in, and any errors like misspellings should be readily apparent
- The hashtables are storing high-level data that can be further mutated later if desired
- Non-cursors and cursors appear to be separate classes of data -- cursors always have the same property type, so that should be extrinsic from cursor entries.

Comment: The path entry is required, the function won't work otherwise. Since priority is understanding, doesn't the OLD way win out over any other minimalist code or also your suggested method, as the person reading has to conceptually then understand the things you said, i.e. lambdas ...etc.

Comment: @Vijay Maximum verbosity does not necessarily mean maximum understanding or readability. In fact, more verbosity can be much less readable and much more bug prone. For example, imagine you're reading this and can only see half the lines on your display. Do you know for sure every path is the same? If they're always being specified, maybe if you scroll down you'll see one that is different -- you don't know for sure. If you specify the path a single time at the top of the file, the reader can reasonably assume it's relevant for all entries.

Comment: Why is it necessary to use a powershell script and not a registry script? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/310516/how-to-add-modify-or-delete-registry-subkeys-and-values-by-using-a-reg